# How to get rid of notes window at login

Tags: xubuntu

Each time I log in on my xubuntu, I get a window titled "Notes - Notes" on the desktop
How can I permanently get rid of this annoying window?

Comment: Does it do it for other users as well? Have you checked your Session and Startup settings to see if it's in the Autostart list?

Comment: @techie007 Altering Session and Startup settings solved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Nice, I'll throw that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your Session and Startup settings to see if it's in the Autostart list.

- Open 'Settings Manager'
- Select 'Session and Startup'
- On the 'Application Autostart' tab, ensure the program you don't want to auto-run is not in the list.

[image]